# custom keys in appSettings.json not working in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I added a CustomSettings section keys in appSettings.json in ASP.NET Core project:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Data Source=..."
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "CustomSettings": {
    "Culture": "es-CO"
  }
}
```

I've not been able to load Culture key in following controller:

```
public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration)
{
   Response.Cookies.Append(
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings")["Culture"])),
                    new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );
}
```

No matter if I do following, always they return NULL:
configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings")["Culture"];
configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings").GetValue("Culture");

I tried help based in [ASP.NET Core: Step by Step Guide to Access appsettings.json in web project and class library](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/asp-net-core-step-by-step-guide-to-access-appsettings-json-in-web-project-and-class-library/) and I've created CustomSettings class with string Culture property and injecting in Startup as follows:

```
        // Load Custom Configuration from AppSettings.json
        services.Configure<Models.CustomSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings"));
```

Accesing by inject IOptions customSettings, the value of 
customSettings.Value.Culture returns NULL.

First Question: ¿What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

Second Question: ¿Why doing following in Index of HomeController throws an exception?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Index(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
   }
}
```

Exception:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[[OmniMerchant.Models.CustomSettings, OmniMerchant, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)

Third Question: I need to set Culture from Starting for all the app in background based on Culture property on appSettings.json, I read [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), but I've not been able to achieve that, ¿How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

First create the modal that matches the appsetting section

```
public class CustomSettings
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

Then register it in the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<CustomSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings"));
```

Then inject it using IOptions where its needed

```
AccountController(IOptions<CustomSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings.Value;
}
```

Comment: I wrote that I've already used that scenerio as you commented and it didn't work. However I'm using the file appsettings.json and I suppose works for any configuration: Debug, Release, etc.

Comment: @AldemarCuartasCarvajal Could you please share the CustomSettings.cs class

Comment: namespace OmniMerchant.Models
{
    public class CustomSettings
    {
        public string Culture
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}

Comment: but alredy worked. As Thowk mentioned in point number 1, when I added the section CustomSettings and the key Culture in appsettings.Development.json worked fine!. I don't understand well if for example ConnectionStrings section exists only in the default appsettings.json but not in appsettings.Development.json, why that is well recognized when debugging but it doesn't with my custom section?

Answer (score 4):

1. Why configuration section values are null?

By default there are two config files. For Release build and one for Debug. Have you checked that you actually editing the correct one (probably *appsettings.Development.json*)

2. Why DI is not working.

In .NET Core basically you can use DI in two ways. By injecting it in constructor or directly in method. In the second option you have to use special attribute [[FromServices]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection)

Comment: Project created just one file appsettings.json by default, I know that there are different target environments as you mention but I suppose the default created appsettings.json works for any configuration: Debug, Release, etc.

Comment: As you mentioned in point number 1, when I added the section CustomSettings and the key Culture in appsettings.Development.json worked fine!. I don't understand well if for example ConnectionStrings section exists only in the default appsettings.json but not in appsettings.Development.json, why that is well recognized when debugging but it doesn't with my custom section?

Comment: That's right. It should not be required to add new config-value to all of your environments just to primary one. I would check how your Configuration is builded. Order of added .json to it is important. So if your main appsettings are the first one, then it they should be read correctly.

Answer (score 4):

In your application properties -> Debug section -> Environment variables

If this is set
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`: Development

It will use `appsettings.Development.json`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me -- is it supposed to append to the appsettings.json file at run time, or does the framework load/replace the values in memory?

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR;** Your appsettings.json file needs to be in the same working directory as your dll file.

You need to make sure that you are running the app from it's working directory.

For example, if your dll's are built to the `bin` folder, the following won't work:

```
cd bin
dotnet run app.dll
```

Because the `appsettings.json` file is not in the same folder as the dll that you are running from.

However if you are in the directory that the `appsettings.json` file is in, the current working directory will be set and that file will be read.

```
dotnet run bin/app.dll
```

If using VS Code `launch.json` you can set the `cwd` property to achieve this.

Comment: after countless effort, this is the solution

Answer (score 2):

I had problems reading from different configuration files until I added each of them specifically in the Startup constructor like below:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")                //***
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json")    //***
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I think but probably you can solve it by setting "HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath" manualy.

Try to add the following code in the Startup method in Startup.cs:

```
if (env.EnvironmentName== "Production")
{
    env.ContentRootPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
}
```

or hardcode path like this:

```
if (env.EnvironmentName == "Production")
{
    env.ContentRootPath = "/var/aspnetcore/...";
}
```

---

For example if your files located in "**/var/aspnetcore/my_ASP_app**", the startup method should be something like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.EnvironmentName== "Production")
    {
        //env.ContentRootPath = "/var/aspnetcore/my_ASP_app";
        env.ContentRootPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
    //env.ContentRootPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();//you can write this line outside of IF block.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();

}
```

It is better to use **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()** instead of hardcoding.

This worked for me in **Linux Ubuntu** with **nginx**, but I don't know if it is applicable for your enviornment.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922278/200653). For asp.net core 2.0 you don't need to set the directory, you just need to launch it with the correct current working directory.